# stormcrawler selenium duplicate processing

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

I am using stormcrawler with selenium remote driver protocol via provided navigation filter plugin. If my navigation filter executes really long time (url is processed correctly  and updates status to "fetched" in mysql  database), somehow crawler picks up the same url from the mysql table to fetch again. So status update happens after url is in the queue again.  What parameter I can configure to avoid this? I tried to set all components to threads= 1 and it is still happening.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the timeout setting in Storm. See [conf in archetype](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/archetype/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/crawler-conf.yaml#L9) where it is set to 300 secs. After this time has passed since emitting the tuple, the tuple will be failed and its URL removed from the spout's cache of URLs being processed. Therefore when the spout queries MySQL again, the URL will be sent down the topology. Having a tuple failed does not stop the processing of the URL though, and the status will eventually get updated as you noticed.

One option is to set the value of the timeout to be large enough so that whatever you do in the navigation filter has time to complete or change your logic so that it takes less time.